# Web Development with BIM 360 and Forge - Backend

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

Anybody recommend any backends or frameworks for Forge?

I'm seeing resources for Nodejs, PHP, .Net Core and others which are for the backend.
Are any of these any more convenient or dependable with Forge than the others? 
I also know Python and thought Django would be another option but I don't see too many resources on the Python side of things.

Any perspectives on the tools (pro or con) would be great.
The more I understand the kinds of tech stacks, user projects and ways people use Forge to expand on BIM 360 and other APIs the more it can help me and the community get familiar with the service.

Answer (score 0):

This relies completely on the excisting stack used by your company. Forge is a collection of API's accessible via endpoints.

Any library just abstracts the calls away in a accesible way. I've had moderate succes with the dotnet core Forge package, it works very well but you are giving away some strict typing.

If you dont wanna be bound by abstractions made by other people, create your own ! This will ultimately lead to the most lightweight solution since you are only creating what you need.

Cheers